# drawing ellipses/hyperbolas in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw ellipses, hyperbolas in R. 
How can I do it using ggplot2?
Let me give an example

```
x^2 +3xy+ 4x+ 2y+ 2y^2 = 0
```

for

```
x between -2 and 2
y between -2 and 2
```

Comment: Are you looking for a general contour line plotting function or simply to draw an ellipse? There is a conflict between the title of your Q and the content.

Comment: I changed the title accordingly. Thanks

Comment: If you can get a set of (x, y) points that satisfy the equation into a data frame, then geom_path() is your friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Construct a data field:

```
d <- transform(expand.grid(x=seq(-2,2,length=51),
            y=seq(-2,2,length=51)),z=x^2+3*x*y+4*x+2*y+2*y^2)
```

Make a basic `geom_contour` plot with each level coloured differently:

```
g1 <- qplot(x,y,z=z,data=d,colour=factor(..level..),geom="contour")
```

Now get rid of the lines for all but the "0" level.  This depends on `stat_contour` picking zero as one of its contour levels, which might be fragile under some circumstances ... (It's not obvious to me that `stat_contour()` allows control of what levels are chosen, equivalent to the `levels` argument to `contour()` or `contourLines()` in base R -- if it did, this process would be a little bit easier.  One might submit a wishlist item to https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues , if one cared enough about this ...)

```
g1 + scale_colour_discrete(breaks="0",limits=c("0","0"),na.value=NA,
                          guide="none")
```

[image]