# plotting matrix equation in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, parametric-equations

I'm new to R and I need to plot the quadratic matrix equation:

`x^T A x + b^T x + c = 0`

in R^2, with A being a 2x2, b a 2x1, and c a constant. The equation is for a boundary that defines classes of points. I need to plot that boundary for `x0 = -6...6`, `x1 = -4...6`. My first thought was generate a bunch of points and see where they are zero, but it depends on the increment between the numbers (most likely I'm not going guess what points are zero).

Is there a better way than just generating a bunch of points and seeing where it is zero or multiplying it out? Any help would be much appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to generate a sample set to plot.  Can you give any more information on your inputs and what your expected plot should look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a symmetric matrix `A`,

eg

```
 # A = | a    b/2 |
 #     | b/2  c   |
```

and your equation represents a conic section, you can use the [`conics` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/conics/)

What you need is a vector of coefficients `c(a,b,c,d,e,f)` representing

```
a.x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f
```

In your case, say you have

```
 A <- matrix(c(2,1,1,2))

 B <- c(-20,-28)
 C <- 10


# create the vector
v <- append(c(diag(A),B,C),A[lower.tri(A)]*2), 1)



 conicPlot(v)
```

[image]

You could easily wrap the `multiplication out` into a simple function

```
# note this does no checking for symmetry or validity of arguments

expand.conic <- function(A, B, C){
 append(c(diag(A),B,C),A[lower.tri(A)]*2), 1)
}
```

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I needed. would you have any idea how to make it into a ggplot object?

Comment: Not without  rewriting conicPlot and `conics:::plotEllipse`.  You could look how these work, and write your own wrapper to create a data.frame that you could use with ggplot.

Comment: You could also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922740/drawing-ellipses-hyperbolas-in-r for a `ggplot2` approach

Comment: I'm just marveling at the beauty of this answer. Wish I could pass rep over to your bucket.