# How to plot an ellipse defining the trajectory of planets in R

Tags: r, plot, ellipse

i have 3 planets, the first one with eccentricity = 0,70 and semi major axis = 900, the second one with eccentricity 0,80 and semi major axis = 1200 and the third one  with eccentricity = 0,90 and semi major axis = 1500.
is there a way to plot this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820683/how-to-plot-ellipse-given-a-general-equation-in-r) might be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [drawing ellipses/hyperbolas in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922740/drawing-ellipses-hyperbolas-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

`ggforce` package has `geom_ellipse`. Just one thing, you need to provide both minor and major axis, but it's easy to calculate minor axis from major and eccentricity.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

planets <- 
  tribble(
    ~e, ~a,
    0.7, 900,
    0.8, 1200,
    0.9, 1500
  ) %>% 
  mutate(name = letters[1:n()]) %>% 
  # calculate minor axis
  mutate(b = a*sqrt(1-e^2)) %>% 
  # centers
  mutate(x0 = 0, y0 = 0)

planets %>% 
  ggplot(aes(color = name)) +
  geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = x0, y0 = y0, a = a, b = b, angle = 0)) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>